# How to update each row by it's own value encrypted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption

I'm trying to update every value of a column.

I'm trying to apply encryption for an existing database

```
$query = $this->db->query("select firstname from user");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
$encr = $this->encryption->encrypt($row['firstname']);

$this->db->set('firstname', $encr);
$this->db->update('user');   
}
```

The result take the first row, encrypt it, then apply it to all rows, while it suppose to update each row individually taking in consideration its own value. What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !
I forgot to specify the id. This worked :

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from user");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
$id = $row['id'];
$encr = $this->encryption->encrypt($row['firstname']);

$this->db->set('firstname', $encr);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('user');  
}
```

A reminder to always check the assumptions.

Comment: Also, look at prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your ID, you don't have a `where` clause.

```
$this->db->where('id', $row['id']); // or whatever is the unique column name.
```